# ASP - How to assign Javascript Variable to an ASP form group

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Noob question, I'm having trouble understanding what I should do to achieve this.

I currently have the following Enum in my models:

```
  public enum Size
{
    Round = 1,
    Square,
    Oval,
    Sheet,
}
```

I also have the following div component:

```
<div id ="shapeSelect" name ="shape" class="form-group" onchange="myFunction()">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Size)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

I am trying to assign a javascript variable to the drop down list:

```
var x = document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value;
```

and just display it:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Selected shape: " + x + ". ";
```

However, assigning the javascript value to the dropdown just displays the object reference. How can I assign it directly to the value(round,square,oval,sheet), or is this not possible in this context?

Comment: `var x = document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value;` will try to pull the value from the `div` container, not from the select element within. You'd want `var x = document.querySelector("#shapeSelect select").value;`